# What does mean parameter offset in function get_inline_bot_results?

Tags: python, pyrogram

I cannot understand what parameter offset did in this function and what's kind of values accept?
I try use integers but there is no effect.

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters
import time


app = Client(
    "my_account",
    api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash,
)


async def main():
    async with app:
        bot_results = await app.get_inline_bot_results(
            "some_bot_name",
            query="some_query",
            offset="???"
        )


app.run(main())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_inline_bot_results) states:

> `offset` (str, optional) – Offset of the results to be returned.

Which is not super helpful but from the [Telegram Docs](https://core.telegram.org/api/bots/inline) shows that it is used for pagination:

> `offset` - If the user scrolls past the first `len(results)` results, and
> `next_offset` field is set, the inline query should be repeated with
> this offset.

Checking the `string` [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/type/string) and [this] GitHub issue, it seems that the `offset` should be a string of an `int` like: `"0"` or `"100"`. Make sure the returned results' length is more than 1 and set the `offset` to `"1"`.

Comment: I think it depends on what bot will return in the next_offset parameter. And what kind of logic the author of the bot place in this return value.

Answer (score 0):

Solution of my problem was not at **offset** parameter but in content of **query** one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).